# omniauth and linkedin => 401: OAuthProblemException while parsing OAuth request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm using the [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) and [omniauth-linkedin](https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin) gems for
general OAuth functionality, but I'm not able to make them play
nice with the [linkedin](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) gem, even when calling `authorize_from_access`
as per [this documentation](https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin#using-it-with-the-linkedin-gem).  Schematically, I'm doing this:

```
GET /auth/linkedin
receive callback at /auth/:provider/callback => sessions#create
auth = Authorization.new(:auth => request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_json)
# at this point I can verify that I'm logged into LinkedIn
client = LinkedIn::Client.new
token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
client.authorize_from_access(token, secret)
client.profile => 401 error
```

I get:

```
LinkedIn::Errors::UnauthorizedError: (401): OAuthProblemException while parsing OAuth request
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?  Does my web server need to have external access?  Or perhaps I'm using the wrong fields from the omniauth.auth structure?  FWIW, token and secret have the form:

```
token = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
secret = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

### configuration notes

- I am running my controller with `force_ssl`.
- I am using localhost:3000 (not externally accessible)

config:

- Ruby version              1.9.3 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0)
- RubyGems version          1.8.15
- Rack version              1.4
- Rails version             3.2.2
- oauth (0.4.7)
- omniauth (1.1.0)
- omniauth-linkedin (0.0.8)
- omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
- linkedin (0.3.7)

### TL;DR

The relevant routes / controllers / models are posted here.

```
# file: config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linked_in, 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
end

# config/routes.rb
Nlp::Application.routes.draw do

  ...
  match "/login" => "sessions#new"
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
  match "/logout" => "sessions#destroy"

end

# app/controller/SessionsController.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    self.current_user = Authorization.authorized_user(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Signed in!"
  end

  def destroy
    self.current_user = nil
    redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Signed out!"
  end

end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  force_ssl

  protected

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
    session[:user_id] = user && user.id
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      redirect_to login_path, :alert => "You must be logged in to access this page."
    end
  end

  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :require_login

end

class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :uid, :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

  # Find User associated with auth's UID and provider, creating one if
  # needed.
  def self.authorized_user(auth)
    authorization = Authorization.where(:uid => auth["uid"], :provider => auth["provider"]).first_or_create! do |authorization| 
      authorization.user = User.where(:name => auth["info"]["name"]).first_or_create!
      authorization.access_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
      authorization.access_token_secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
      authorization.auth = auth.to_json
    end
    authorization.user
  end

end
```